# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot retrieve files with 'spark' scheme without an active SparkEnv

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm very new to spark and cassandra, got one sample from github and tried to run the application from the below link

[spark-on-cassandra-quickstart](https://github.com/boneill42/spark-on-cassandra-quickstart)

After jar file generated, Tried executing with the below syntax

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\softwares\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-submit --class com.github.boneill42.JavaDemo --master spark://localhost:7077
C:\Users\user\git\spark-on-cassandra-quickstart\target/spark-on-cassandra-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar spark://localhost:7077 localhost
```

Below is the issue I'm facing

```
19/06/08 22:59:49 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot retrieve files with 'spark' scheme without an active SparkEnv.
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:690)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.downloadFile(DependencyUtils.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Please help me in resolving the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, It seems you want to start in [standalone mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)

```
spark://HOST:PORT   Connect to the given Spark standalone cluster master.
The port must be whichever one your master is configured to use, which is 7077 by default.
```

Do you start spark master and worker first ?

launch master

```
./sbin/start-master.sh
```

launch worker

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker  spark://localhost:7077 -c 1 -m 512M
```

After start master and worker, then you can submit your job again.